# I don't know why the crawler with selenium stop in the middle of crawling

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

I'am crawling the result of google search but I get continuously this error message below in the middle of crawling.

I don't know why and I wonder how I could fix it.

Additionally I'm using selenium and python on Jupyter Notebook.
VS code shows same error.

I wanted to enter to some recruite site and crawl information of company. So, the process what I made something like this: input search keyword > enter > click first link > if there are the information I want, crawl > if not, enter another link, check information and crawl.

My code is as below:

```
def get_info(temp_dict, ceo): 
    if '/' in temp_dict['ceo']:
        ceo_list = temp_dict['ceo'].split('/')
        if ceo in ceo_list:
            return temp_dict['industry']
        else:
            return {'new_ceo': temp_dict['ceo'], 'indu': temp_dict['industry']}
    
    elif temp_dict['ceo'] != ceo:
        return {'new_ceo': temp_dict['ceo'], 'indu': temp_dict['industry']}

    else:
        return temp_dict['industry']

 
def crawl_comp_info(compName, ceo):
    search_word = compName + " //site name//"
#     print(compName, ceo, search_word)
    
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, chrome_options=chrome_options)    
    driver.get('http://google.com')
    driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
   
    search_box = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
    search_button = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "btnK")
    
    search_box.send_keys(search_word)
    search_button.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(1)

    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.LC20lb.MBeuO.DKV0Md')[0].send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(3)

    comp_info = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.field')

    temp_dict = {}
    for i in comp_info:
        info = i.text.split('\n')
        try:
            temp_dict[info[0]] = info[1]
            temp_dict[info[2]] = info[3]
        except:
            temp_dict[info[0]] = info[1]

    if '대표자' in temp_dict.keys():
        result = get_info(temp_dict, ceo)
    else:
        k = driver.current_url
        refresh_url = k + "?tabType=I"
        driver.get(refresh_url)
        driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

        comp_info = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.field')
        temp_dict = {}
        for i in comp_info:
            info = i.text.split('\n')
            try:
                temp_dict[info[0]] = info[1]
                temp_dict[info[2]] = info[3]
            except:
                temp_dict[info[0]] = info[1]


        if 'ceo' in temp_dict.keys():
            result = get_info(temp_dict, ceo)
            
        else:
            result = "N/A"

    
    return result

    driver.quit()
```

I've been tyring to change code related in click from `click()` to `.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` but the same issue goes on.

```
ElementNotInteractableException           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-de56e7f281b4> in <module>
----> 1 df_1['info'] = df_1[['companyName', 'ceo']].progress_apply(lambda x: crawl_comp_info(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/std.py in inner(df, func, *args, **kwargs)
    812                 # on the df using our wrapper (which provides bar updating)
    813                 try:
--> 814                     return getattr(df, df_function)(wrapper, **kwargs)
    815                 finally:
    816                     t.close()

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   7766             kwds=kwds,
   7767         )
-> 7768         return op.get_result()
   7769 
   7770     def applymap(self, func, na_action: Optional[str] = None) -> DataFrame:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    183             return self.apply_raw()
    184 
--> 185         return self.apply_standard()
    186 
    187     def apply_empty_result(self):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    274 
    275     def apply_standard(self):
--> 276         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    277 
    278         # wrap results

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    288             for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    289                 # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 290                 results[i] = self.f(v)
    291                 if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    292                     # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/std.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    807                     # take a fast or slow code path; so stop when t.total==t.n
    808                     t.update(n=1 if not t.total or t.n < t.total else 0)
--> 809                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
    810 
    811                 # Apply the provided function (in **kwargs)

<ipython-input-11-de56e7f281b4> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df_1['info'] = df_1[['companyName', 'ceo']].progress_apply(lambda x: crawl_comp_info(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)

<ipython-input-9-e3373584362d> in crawl_comp_info(compName, ceo)
     24     time.sleep(1)
     25 
---> 26     driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.LC20lb.MBeuO.DKV0Md')[0].send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
     27     time.sleep(3)
     28 

~/anaconda3/envs/eric/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in send_keys(self, *value)
    538                 value = '\n'.join(remote_files)
    539 
--> 540         self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
    541                       {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
    542                        'value': keys_to_typing(value)})

~/anaconda3/envs/eric/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    708             params = {}
    709         params['id'] = self._id
--> 710         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    711 
    712     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~/anaconda3/envs/eric/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    422         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    423         if response:
--> 424             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    425             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    426                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda3/envs/eric/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    245                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    246             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 247         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    248 
    249     def _value_or_default(self, obj: Mapping[_KT, _VT], key: _KT, default: _VT) -> _VT:

ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: headless chrome=98.0.4758.102)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55677cbb2b33 <unknown>
#1 0x55677c67b56f <unknown>
#2 0x55677c6abd0e <unknown>
#3 0x55677c6ab304 <unknown>
#4 0x55677c6cf062 <unknown>
#5 0x55677c6a5fa3 <unknown>
#6 0x55677c6cf16e <unknown>
#7 0x55677c6e22fb <unknown>
#8 0x55677c6cef53 <unknown>
#9 0x55677c6a4a0a <unknown>
#10 0x55677c6a5ad5 <unknown>
#11 0x55677cbe42fd <unknown>
#12 0x55677cbfd4bb <unknown>
#13 0x55677cbe60d5 <unknown>
#14 0x55677cbfe145 <unknown>
#15 0x55677cbd9aaf <unknown>
#16 0x55677cc1aba8 <unknown>
#17 0x55677cc1ad28 <unknown>
#18 0x55677cc3548d <unknown>
#19 0x7f4e6df386db <unknown>
```

I'm new here, so if I'm missing something to put, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: You will need to include details of the page you are scraping and the code up to that point in order for people to be able to help you.

Comment: @ljdyer Thank you for your comment. I've editted by putting my code. Is it enought or do I have to put another information?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @melpark how about the URL for the site you are scraping? apologies if it's there and I don't see it. The error you are getting is saying that you are trying to interact with an element that can't be interacted with so in order to diagnose the problem I'd need to take a look at the page.

Comment: Actually I assign search word to a variable "search_word" and makes crawler search that keyword on google. The search_word is like "삼성전자 잡코리아" sorry for that is Korean which means "samsung+HRcompanyName"